# Remove "Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell" header in Visual Studio Terminal

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Whenever I open the terminal in Visual Studio, I get the following boilerplate header:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell v17.5.1
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
```

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Developer PowerShell]

Looking at the terminal settings in `Options > Environment > Terminal`, I'm using the following shell location:

```bash
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe
```

Along with the following arguments:

```
-NoExit -Command "& { Import-Module """$env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell -SkipAutomaticLocation -SetDefaultWindowTitle -InstallPath $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\..\}"
```

Normally, you can remove the powershell header text by adding the [`-NoLogo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-nologo) flag which "*Hides the copyright banner at startup.*", but that doesn't seem to have an effect here.

I think this is being generated from the [`Enter-VsDevShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019) portion.

The reason this is particularly annoying is I usually have the terminal pinned to the bottom with minimal height, so there's a very high demand on visual real estate.

Any way to remove the startup text here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `*>$null` to silence all output from `Enter-VsDevShell`
- In general, use `\"` to escape embedded `"` chars. (which works with both `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) and `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell (Core) 7+).

  - In this particular case, embedded quoting is *not* needed, because the paths start with an (environment) variable reference and are followed by literal subpaths that don't require quoting.
- Remove the unnecessary enclosure in `& { ... }` - just `...` will do.

```bash
-NoExit -Command "Import-Module $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll; Enter-VsDevShell -SkipAutomaticLocation -SetDefaultWindowTitle -InstallPath $env:VSAPPIDDIR\..\..\ *>$null"
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is accessing VS Developer PS from Windows Terminal, you can do:

`-SkipAutomaticLocation -DevCmdArguments """-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64 -no_logo"""`

That is, add the `-no_logo` flag in the `DevCmdArguments` arg.